# C# Is there a way to use DllImport with generic method types?

Tags: c#

My question is that I want to use `DllImport` with a generic method and I can't get it to work.

I'm using a C# library called "newtonsoft.json" and I want to use `DllImport` with this method:

```
[DllImport(@"path to my dll")] public static T
public static extern DeserializeObject<T>(string value);
```

It tells me that `DllImport` attribute cannot be applied to generic method types.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json` is a managed library, no need to `[DllImport]` it.  Add a reference to the assembly, add a `using Newtonsoft.Json` to the top of your C# file, and start using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` right away.

Comment: I don't really understand. NewtonSoft.Json is a .NET library, you should just be able to add a reference to that DLL into your project (if you installed it via NuGet then this has probably already been done for you), and then put a  `using` statement at the top of your file to give you access to its methods. DLLImport is meant for importing methods from non-.NET DLLs into your code.

Comment: @SamPearson Thanks, but when i've copied the .exe file to another location it gave me a missing dll error, now i've noticed that i just need to copy the .dll file to the location with the exe. I've solved this.

Comment: you can't just copy an exe, that's not how you deploy a .NET application. I suggest you do some research into this, there are plenty of tutorials, examples, blogs and other resources online. Start with Microsoft's.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've added the DLL file using Clicking on the project > Add > Reference and selected the library, and then i've just copied the library with the .exe file.